# Rails helper enum to view uninitialized constant issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, constants

I keep getting

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::BLAHBLAH1
```

When I use the `BLAHBLAH1` in the erb file it won't work, but if I prefix it with the helper name `BlahBlahHelper::BLAHBLAH1` it works.
The helper is `blahblah_helper.erb` with contents of:

```
module BlahBlahHelper
  BLAHBLAH1 = 0
end
```

The file name of the view is `blah_blah.html.erb`. I know I have the proper naming convention for view to helper as I have tested that.

Would the helper being in a subdirectory of view be an issue?

Is there a way to get it to work without having to prefix the helper name?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I get `uninitialized constant BLAHBLAH1`

Comment: What's the controller name? Unless it's `BlahBlahsController` and you're using a specific Rails version that is expected behaviour!

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I am using `reports_controller.rb` but that renders the view file. The error is happening in the view.

Comment: Try putting `helper BlahBlahHelper` in the `reports_controller` after the `class`

Answer (score 2):

The helper module is only loaded automatically when it has the matching name with controller's name.

So in your case you have 2 options:

1)

```
include BlahBlahHelper # in controller, same as `helper BlahBlahHelper`
```

2)

rename the controller to be `BlahBlahController`.

Ok, as edikgat tried to point in comments the issue here is the constants resolution.

To use a constant you have to reference it with the full name, because constants are not being included with module, only it's methods.

Have a read through [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) on constants loading in Rails.

Comment: absolutely NO.
all helpers are included to all views classes
you can do "self.class.ancestors" in you view to be sure

Comment: @edikgat I can not really understand what you have written. You can write in Russian may be - so that at least I understand what you intended to say. + please explain your downvote (cause, as I say - I have no idea what you mean)

Comment: 1) хелперы включаются во все анонимные классы вьюх без относительно  к их именам - это одна из причин почему их не стоит широко использовать
2) константы никуда не включаются. Механизм поиска констант в руби отличается от механизма поиска методов. там суть в том что костанта будет искаться в более глобальном пространстве имен, если не была найдена в локальном, итд

Comment: @AndreyDeineko at russian as you wish

Comment: @edikgat after your previous comment edit I understood the point. Regarding constants resolution mechanism in Ruby - I'm aware of it, it is just that I somehow missed that the issue is with constant, and replied as if the problem was with method.

Answer (score 0):

This happends because helpers like other modules is include to views only their methods. There are no way to include constants